# After resize and after reduce get error on parted

Tags: lvm, proxmox

#### Scenario

I expanded the disk space, from a kvm in proxmox.

By mistake expand instead of 50 GB expand 500GB

Well, when I did the vps check with `dmesg | grep vdb` and with `fdisk -l /dev/vdb | grep ^/dev` I realized my mistake

Choose to stop the machine and do a disk shrink with

```
lvreduce -L -400G /dev/lvm/vm-109-disk-1

 WARNING: Reducing active logical volume to 800.00 GiB.
  THIS MAY DESTROY YOUR DATA (filesystem etc.)
Do you really want to reduce lvm/vm-109-disk-1? [y/n]: and
  Size of logical volume lvm/vm-109-disk-1 changed from 1.22 TiB (320000 extents) to 800.00 GiB (204800 extents).
  Logical volume lvm/vm-109-disk-1 successfully resized.
```

Now when I start the system and went to work as I usually do when I enlarge the disk, I found an inconsistency that does not allow me to fix the real space.

Usually to expand I do the following (1 is partition grow)

```
parted /dev/vdb
(parted) print
(parted) resizepart 1 100%
(parted) quit
```

Previus

```
pvresize /dev/vdb1
  Physical volume "/dev/vdb1" changed
  1 physical volume (s) resized or updated / 0 physical volume (s) not resized
```

But I see I don't change

```
pvscan
  PV / dev / vda2 VG lvm lvm2 [<24.51 GiB / 0 free]
  PV / dev / vdb1 VG lvm lvm2 [<600.00 GiB / 0 free]
```

If I try to use parted to see the state both in console and starting the vps with LiveParted I have the same error

```
GNU Parted 3.1
Using / dev / vdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Error: Can't make partition off disk!
Model: Virtio Block Device (virtblk)
Disk / dev / vdb: 859GB
Sector size (logical / physical): 512B / 512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

Vps is work perfectly but disk is unresizeable...

Comment: I see that you have resized the partitions, but I do not see any evidence that you are resizing the filesystems. Have you made sure that the filesystem size is resized to the size of the partitions?

Comment: I can't resize filsesystem beacuse ¡parte get error. 
On host, logical volume has a new size 600 original >  ~1250 GB after error -> resize o reducee to 800: Now is problem.... On VPS I can't   resize phisical drive /dev/vdb (disk on host is a resized logical volume)

Comment: Any update on what you did?

Comment: Yes. Close issues, create a new server and after migrate content. End of problem. I've tried some tips but not work and after backp snapshots, I get the new server way. @Gordster